Manwha/manhua where mc has 2 helping spirits; one is a black knight and other one is an all-knowing mage,
In the manwha/manhua the mc has ability copy other peoples skills even unique ones upon killing them.
He started with only the black knight spirit which was named something like emperor which he later on used as dungeon alias.
